# Lightweight, collapsible Executor implementation?

Tags: java, android, executorservice, executor

I'm building a mobile app for Android and I need to pool HTTP requests for each of my List adapters. I basically want an `ExecutorService` implementation that "collapses," ie: it will use up to *n* threads, but as threads complete, they will immediately expire, making it really lightweight. If there's high demand, it'll just dump tasks into a queue which will wait for threads to become available. Is there a way to do this without writing an `ExecutorService` myself or should I just get my hands dirty and do it?

Comment: Seems amazing to me that Android does not provide an executor similar to java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.  Be warned writing a good and thread-safe executor is harder than it seems - I know, I've done it for Java 1.1.

Comment: Does nobody search documentation anymore?  I did a simple google for "Android Executor" and was taken in the first hit to the documentation for http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html which had a direct link to the various executors, including ThreadPoolExecutor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it work to use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with its [`keepAliveTime`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setKeepAliveTime%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) set to zero?

e.g.

```
int core = 5;
int max = 20;
new ThreadPoolExecutor(core, max, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>())
```

From the docs for `setKeepAliveTime()`:

> A time value of zero will cause excess threads to terminate immediately after executing tasks.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. So something like `new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 8, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>())` would give me a pool with a minimum size of 0, maximum size of 8, and will kill threads after they're done? Or is the first parameter more or less irrelevant in this case because of the timeout?

Comment: With 0 and 8, the pool would allocate 0 threads initially. When a task is submitted to the executor, if no threads are available, it will allocate a new one to handle it. Up to 8 concurrent threads could be allocated, and anything that gets submitted while all 8 are being used will simply remain in the Queue until an executor becomes available. One thing I'm not sure of is whether or not a thread will terminate before grabbing the next task from the Queue if one is available. In the absence of documentation stating otherwise, I'm inclined to believe it will.

Comment: For what it's worth, I wouldn't recommend having a core pool size of 0 along with a keepAliveTime of 0. It seems to me that your threads would be constantly being terminated/reconstructed, which would negate the "lightweight" criterion you're going for. I can't imagine having a few core threads waiting in the background will bog down your application. As with any performance concern, write your code, and then profile your application to see if it's behaving the way you need it to. If it's not, refactor.

Comment: FWIW: I would be stunned if the implementation let a thread die when there were tasks on the queue, only to create another one to take over from the one which dies - it would be a significantly more difficult implementation.

Comment: The keep-alive time is documented as pertaining to idle time: `excess threads will be terminated if they have been idle for more than the keepAliveTime`, which would seem to preclude the thread from dieing when there's tasks pending.  However the documentation for allowCoreThreadTimeout seems to indicate the converse: `To avoid continual thread replacement, the keep-alive time must be greater than zero when setting true`.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't figure out from the documentation what it would do if there were still queued tasks needing to be processed. Left as an exercise to the reader, I guess.